# get the n latest changelists in a specific period

Tags: c#, perforce

I wish to get the latest 20 changelists in this period. How can I modify the options?

This is very important for me because I will collect some statistics from the data provided by perforce. Here is my code:

```
string deppath1 = "//obms/...";
P4Command cm1 = new P4Command(ps, "changes", true, String.Format("{0}", deppath1));
 Options opchanges = new Options();
opchanges.Add("2012/04/01", "now");
 P4CommandResult results1 = cm1.Run(opchanges);
if (results1 != null)
Console.WriteLine("ggh");
TaggedObjectList listfiledown1 = new TaggedObjectList();
listfiledown1 = (results1.TaggedOutput);

foreach (TaggedObject obj in listfiledown1)
 {
   foreach (String s in obj.Keys)
    {
        String value = "n/a";
        obj.TryGetValue(s, out value);
        Console.WriteLine(s+""+value);
        Console.WriteLine("********");
    }
 }
```

Comment: What are you seeing when you run the code..? have you stepped thru the code..? what are you wanting to do in the `foreach` loop..

Comment: for exemple get who did the change when i run the code there is an error output wich is not in client view so the the result1.taggedoutput will be null thank you @DJKRAZE you are always helping me

Comment: well what object  keeps that information..is it TaggedObject..? I can't see in your code where you are even capturing who made the change.. please provide more information as to how you even know who's doing what.. be more specific

Comment: @DJKRAZE obj contain all that we need :) who and when ....

Comment: if found a solution :) the problem was in the option so we have to omit the @ now how can i add the parameter of the number of changelist thank you @DJKRAZE you are always helping me

Comment: are you saving that you need to separate the list for example "@ghassenfst" if so then you can do something like `var changeList = obj.Split('@');` basically Create a List<string> out side of the foreach loop and inside the loop add the individuals to the list..can you show me what the output looks like when you loop thru the foreach..I can write you something once I see what it is the output looks like.. show me something with at least 3 or 4 items please

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26648/discussion-between-dj-kraze-and-ghassenfst)

Comment: you didn't understand that i found a solution now i am trying to give something better i am trying to add a new option which is the number                                                             **the output is: changenumber+timeofchange+labelofchange+client+user etc**

Comment: God, I hate perforce...sorry, a bit of ptsd there, so many painful memories of working with it on past gigs...my sympathies to anyone forced to use it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
opchanges.Add("-m n -u edk -s submitted 2010/04/01", "now");
```

n the number of changes you need.

Answer (score 3):

```
 opchanges.Add("  -l 20  edk -s    submitted   2010/04/01", "now");
```

Comment: Since the original question asked for the latest 20 changes, that should probably be -m 20, not -m 5.